# HTML sample file not indexing in Solr 8.8

Tags: solr

I am trying out indexing the exampledocs in the examples folder with the SimplePostTool on windows 10 using solr 8.8.  All the documents index except sample.html. For that file I get the following error:

```
PS C:\solr-8.8.0> java -jar -Dc=gettingstarted -Dauto example\exampledocs\post.jar example\exampledocs\sample.html
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update...
Entering auto mode. File endings considered are xml,json,jsonl,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt,log
POSTing file sample.html (text/html) to [base]/extract
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #404 (Not Found) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update/extract?resource.name=C%3A%5Csolr-8.8.0%5Cexample%5Cexampledocs%5Csample.html&literal.id=C%3A%5Csolr-8.8.0%5Cexample%5Cexampledocs%5Csample.html
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/solr/gettingstarted/update/extract</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>404</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Not Found</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>default</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update/extract?resource.name=C%3A%5Csolr-8.8.0%5Cexample%5Cexampledocs%5Csample.html&literal.id=C%3A%5Csolr-8.8.0%5Cexample%5Cexampledocs%5Csample.html
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update...
Time spent: 0:00:00.086
```

However the json and all other file types index with no problem. For example:

```
PS C:\solr-8.8.0> java -jar -Dc=gettingstarted -Dauto example\exampledocs\post.jar example\exampledocs\books.json
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update...
Entering auto mode. File endings considered are xml,json,jsonl,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt,log
POSTing file books.json (application/json) to [base]/json/docs
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update...
```

Just following this tutorial:https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_8/post-tool.html#post-tool-windows-support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extracting request handler that allows indexing of rich documents has to be enabled before it can be used. If you look at the paths in both your request, you can see that your first request goes to `/extract` and it gives a 404, while your second request goes to `/update` and works.

You can find a description of [how to enable and configure the endpoint in the Solr documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html#configuring-the-extractingrequesthandler-in-solrconfig-xml):

> If you are not working with an example configset, the jars required to use Solr Cell will not be loaded automatically. You will need to configure your solrconfig.xml to find the ExtractingRequestHandler and its dependencies:
>
> ```
> <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../..}/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
> <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />
> ```
>
> You can then configure the ExtractingRequestHandler in solrconfig.xml. The following is the default configuration found in Solr’s _default configset, which you can modify as needed:
>
> ```
> <requestHandler name="/update/extract"
>                 startup="lazy"
>                 class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
>   <lst name="defaults">
>     <str name="lowernames">true</str>
>     <str name="fmap.content">_text_</str>
>   </lst>
> </requestHandler>
> ```

Comment: Thanks Mats.  Just following a tutorial I did not see that changing the configuration file was part of the getting started example.  All the other file formats just worked.

Comment: I copied the solrconf.xml file from a 7.7.3 solr installation to the gettingstarted/conf folder and restarted the server and indexing worked.  Comparing the config files between versions it appears the code above was left out of the 8.8.0 _default/config/solrconfig.xml file.

Comment: @MatsLindh's answer helps me in correcting the collection's config on Solr 9.0.0. I have captured it here: https://twitter.com/baatchitweet/status/1570656491958587395